# I am getting an error while trying to make a POST request of the "workout" object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, api, redux

After inserting the data in the form and clicking submit, I get this error PATCH http://localhost:5000/workouts/null 404 (Not Found) at the first attempt. After that, everything works fine, but at all first trials, I get this error. The first object might pe sending an invalid id to the database.

This is my workout object.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";


const workoutSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    category:String,
    difficulty:String,
    exercisesNames:[String],
    selectedFile:String,
    likeCount: {
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    postedAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:new Date()
    }
});

const WorkoutMessage=mongoose.model('WorkoutMessage',workoutSchema);

export default WorkoutMessage;
```

These are my requests

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import WorkoutMessage from '../models/workoutMessage.js'

const router = express.Router();

export const getWorkouts=async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const workoutMessages=await WorkoutMessage.find();
        console.log(workoutMessages);

        res.status(200).json(workoutMessages);
    }catch(error){
        res.status(404).json({message:error.message});
    }
}


export const createWorkout=async (req,res)=>{
    const workout=req.body;

    const newWorkoutMessage=new WorkoutMessage(workout);
    try{
        await newWorkoutMessage.save();

        res.status(201).json(newWorkoutMessage);
    }catch(error)
    {
        res.status(409).json({message:error.message});
    }
}

export const updateWorkout=async(req,res)=>{
    const { id:_id }=req.params;
    const workout=req.body;

    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id)) return res.status(404).send(`No workout with that ${_id}`);

        const updatedWorkout=await WorkoutMessage.findByIdAndUpdate(_id,{...workout,_id},{new:true});

    res.json(updateWorkout);
}

export const deleteWorkout=async(req,res)=>{
    const { id }=req.params;

    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
    return res.status(404).send('No workout with that id');

    await WorkoutMessage.findByIdAndRemove(id);

    res.json({message:"Workout deleted successfully"});
}

export default router;
```

Here I have the action functions from the client:

```
import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE } from '../constants/actionTypes';

import * as api from '../api';

export const getWorkouts=()=> async (dispatch)=>{
    try{
        const {data}=await api.fetchWorkouts();

        dispatch({type:FETCH_ALL,payload:data});
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }

}

export const createWorkout=(workout)=>async(dispatch)=>{
    try{
            const {data}=await api.createWorkout(workout);

            dispatch({type:CREATE,payload:data});
            console.log(data);
    }catch(error){
            console.log(error.message);
    }
}

export const updateWorkout=(id,workout)=>async(dispatch)=>{
    try{
        const {data}=await api.updateWorkout(id,workout);

        dispatch({type:UPDATE,payload:data})
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const deleteWorkout=(id)=>async (dispatch)=>{
    try{
        await api.deleteWorkout(id);

        dispatch({type:DELETE,payload:id});
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the Form component, where I fill in the data for making the requests.

```
const Form=({ currentId, setCurrentId=()=>{} })=>{
    const [workoutData, setWorkoutData]=useState({
        category:'',difficulty:'', exercisesNames:'',selectedFile:''
    });

    const workout = useSelector((state) => (currentId ? state.workouts.find((workout) => workout._id === currentId) : null));
    const dispatch=useDispatch();


    const classes=useStyles();
  
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(workout) setWorkoutData(workout);
    },[workout]);

    const clear = () => {
        setCurrentId(0);
        setWorkoutData({  category:'',difficulty:'', exercisesNames:'',selectedFile:'' });
      };

   
    const handleSubmit=async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(currentId===0){
            dispatch(createWorkout(workoutData));
            clear();
        } else{
            dispatch(updateWorkout(currentId, workoutData));
            clear();
        }
     
    };
  
    return(
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Typography variant="h6"></Typography>
            <TextField name="category" variant="outlined" label="Category" fullWidth value={workoutData.category} onChange={(e)=>setWorkoutData({...workoutData, category:e.target.value})}/>
            <TextField name="difficulty" variant="outlined" label="Difficulty" fullWidth value={workoutData.difficulty} onChange={(e)=>setWorkoutData({...workoutData, difficulty:e.target.value})}/>
            <TextField name="exercisesNames" variant="outlined" label="Exercises names" fullWidth value={workoutData.exercisesNames} onChange={(e)=>setWorkoutData({...workoutData, exercisesNames:e.target.value})}/>
            <div className={classes.fileInput}>
                <FileBase
                    type="file"
                    multiple={false}
                    onDone={({base64})=>setWorkoutData({...workoutData,selectedFile:base64})}
                />
            </div>
            <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Submit</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={clear} fullWidth>Clear</Button>
        </form>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://localhost:5000/workouts/null is not found because there is null instead of workout id in the address.
The problem is this line of handleSubmit function:

```
if(currentId===0){
```

Try to change it to

```
if(!currentId) {
```

it seems like your currentId can be null and in that case you also have to create new workout, not update the existing one